# Explicit matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Calculate explicit the matrices, which arise when $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} \in Mat_2(C)$
is used in the following three polynomials: $f(T)=T^2 +1, \ g(T)=(T-i)(T+i), \ h(T)=\chi_A (T)$ How to do that? Is $h(T)=(T-a)(T-d)$?

Comment: No, $h(T)$ is not $(T-a)(T-d)$. Recall the definition of $\chi_A(T)$ please: it is a certain determinant.

Comment: So it will be: h(T)=(T-a) (T-d) -bc ?

Comment: Yes (but the $bc$ is really an $(-b)(-c)$, of course). Now just substitute $A$ for $T$ into each of these polynomials.

Comment: Ok, Can you tell me, what is the difference between f(T) and g(T)?

Comment: None. They are the same polynomial.